# mtDNA sequencing error rates

Tags: dna, dna-sequencing, mitochondria

What is the method to estimate the error rate in mtDNA sequencing?

E.g. we are given a profile like this:

16069T 16126C 73G 152C

Is there a method, a table of known values, or any other way to say that there is an x% chance of 16069T being incorrect?

I'm asking because I would like to have a method to estimate the probability of the profile being incorrect. Something like:

Perr = Perr(16069T) X Perr(16126C) X Perr(73G) X Perr(152C)